# running python program on virtual machine

Tags: scrapy, google-compute-engine

I created GCP VM (ubunto). I installed python and scrapy.
I would like to run my spider from there, `scrapy crawl test -o test1.csv`
I opened the terminal from gcp and run the spider (worked), it will take at least 3 hours.

How can I make sure when i exit the terminal (browser) the script will continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nohup to make sure the crawling continues:

```
nohup scrapy crawl test -o test1.csv &
```

When you log off, the crawler will continues until it finishes. The & at the end will make the process execute in the background.
To redirect the output to a log file, you can execute it as follows:

```
nohup scrapy crawl test -o test1.csv &> test.log &
```

For a better way to run & deploy spiders on a server, you can checkout [scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: scrapy crawl test -o test1.csv, I already save the scrapy log in a File. does this command solely works?

Comment: sure - just do `nohup scrapy crawl test -o test1.csv &`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a run.py file in the spiders directory. 
document content

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
execute(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'test', '-o', 'test1.csv'])
```

After that

```
nohup python -u run.py > spider_house.log 2>&1 &
```

If the log has been configured inside the crawler and the log will be recorded according to the log output inside the crawler, the log output configured by nohup will not be used.

If a paused sustainable crawl is configured, that is, the JOBDIR= parameter wants to gracefully pause the crawler, so that the next time the crawler starts, the last pause is the crawl. The close crawler method is

```
kill 2 pid
```